# Different line spacing in textmode and mathmode

Tags: equations, line-spacing, setspace

At first I was using `\linespread{2}` but my research told me to use the package `setspace`. I did this and everything is fine however in `align*` environments, my equations get double spaced also which makes it visually unappealing. I tried two options

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
%\displayskipstretch %to avoid stretching math formula
\abovedisplayshortskip=0pt
\belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\belowdisplayskip=0pt
```

which doesn't do anything.

I then tried writing `\singlespace` right before my align environment. This works however there's a very big gap between paragraph and align - see picture. (Note that this happens in the above case also). I would preferably like a single, 1.2, or 1.3 spacing in between equations and doublespace in "text mode"

[image: picture]

edit: after viewing the pdf again, I am okay with the double space (again I would prefer single). However the whitespace between the paragraph and the align is very visually unappealing

Comment: Load the package with the `nodisplayskipstretch` option: `\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}`.

Comment: Idea: Put `\newcommand*\AlignDots[2]{\setbox0\hbox{${}#1{}$}\hbox to\wd0{\hfill$#2$\hfill\strut}}` in the preamble and use `\AlignDots` to get vertically dots aligned correctly (instead of the horizontal ones).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I tried that and it works but there is still a fair bit of gap (although less now)

Comment: @masfenix Then try adding this in the preamble (after loading `setspace`): 
`\doublespacing
\setdisplayskipstretch{0.3}`. Adjust the value `0.3` according to your needs.

Comment: I think the problem is with the "cases" left bracket i have. Anyways, is there a way to also force singlespace in math mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone in future who comes looking, and as this didn't quite fit in a comment, the spacing between the paragraph and the align can be reduced by using a `\vspace` with negative spacing after the `\singlespacing`. Note that there must be a blank line between the preceding paragraph and the `\singlespacing` otherwise it will make that paragraph single spaced.

By using

```
text

\singlespacing
\vspace{-0.8cm}
\begin{align}
    y_1 &= ax_1 + b\\
    y_2 &= ax_2 + b
\end{align}

\doublespacing
text
```

I was able to get reasonable results.